# How to uninstall Macports

Tags: uninstall, homebrew, macports

So I have a MacBook Pro with High Sierra and I needed to download a package manager for an Octave project. I already had Docker before this. So I went and downloaded home-brew, MacPorts and tink, not realizing I only needed one package manager. I only want home brew and need to fully uninstall MacPorts and tink.

- I think I have uninstalled tink but I am not sure how to check.
- I get `sudo: port: command not found` when I type in `sudo port -fp uninstall installed` to uninstall MacPorts, so I am not sure what to do here.

My three questions are

1. How to check if I have fully uninstalled tink and all ports.
2. How to fully uninstall MacPorts.
3. How to correctly configure home-brew and docker so they don't mess each other up.

It was my fault for not knowing I needed just one package manager instead of three.

Comment: Hi Dextro53 and welcome. Next time please properly format your question, it helps to understand your question and you are more likely to get answer you need.

Comment: @VlastimilOvčáčík: Please study Markdown a bit more thoroughly, and try to remember to look at the formatted preview (and ensure that it looks reasonable) before you Save Edits. (See my modification to your edit to the above. Also note: We actively discourage “Thanks” in questions, and we routinely delete them when we edit questions.)

Answer (score 0):

As described in [MacPorts Guide](https://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.uninstalling.html), you are fairly safe if you used

`$ sudo port -fp uninstall installed` – instructions to check follow on the page referenced above

But really there's no pressing reason to uninstall anything except maybe the MacPorts app in Applications. They will sit harmlessly in `/opt/local`. Viceversa, Homebrew apps live elsewhere. I'm not sure about Docker, I believe that's a rather different technology. The underlying "Unix philosophy" of small tools applies to MacOS – You will find lots of small, often redundant, or only
slightly different, apps live in MacOS already. MacPorts and Homebrew and Fink are basically just exposing the Unix underpinnings that are already there. In fact, you can use MacPorts and Homebrew together just fine. You wouldn't remove WordPad and Notepad just because you wanted to get rid of Microsoft Office. Same thing applies here.

Comment: Yes I tried that but it came up with 'sudo: port: command not found'. This according to the website means that the port is not functioning. Also how do I check if I have tink anymore?

Comment: I think you mean Fink but you keep typing Tink. I don't know of a package manager Tink.